# Not possible to configure changelog topics

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a state store backed by a changelog topic. In order to limit the size of the changelog topic I wish to set `cleanup.policy="delete,compact"` for the topic. However, when I'm creating a brand new state store with

```kotlin
val builder = StreamsBuilder()

val changelogConfigs = mapOf(
        "cleanup.policy" to "delete,compact",
        "retention.ms" to "86400000", // 1 day
    )

    builder.addStateStore(
        Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
            Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("state-store"),
            Serdes.String(),
            topicSerdeConfig.inputValueSerde
        ).withLoggingEnabled(changeLogConfigs)
    )
```

the configuration is not applied to the changelog topic. The changelog topic gets the following configuration no matter how I specify `changelogConfigs`:

[image]
[image]

Is this a bug, or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: The `withLoggingEnabled(changeLogConfigs)` has an unreliable behavior. It seems to only work if the `StreamsConfig` when creating the stream is sat properly. No error messages or warnings are given if the `StreamsConfig` is wrong.

Comment: Why is the changelog topic configuration dependent on the Stream setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error, and it is somewhat related to [Kafka Streams: Iterative Development and Blue-Green Deployment | by Brett Jordan | Airwallex Engineering | Medium](https://medium.com/airwallex-engineering/kafka-streams-iterative-development-and-blue-green-deployment-fae88b26e75e)

If I also changed the application.id when creating the state store, the changelog topics were configured properly.

If I only were to change the state store name, effectively making a new state store, and not change the application.id, the state store would be configured with the weird default configuration.